# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Laravel Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently moved my laravel application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have the Elastic Beanstalk cli installed locally. But what I would like to know how would I run a php artisan command. I have many of these that I use at random times.

Also will I need any config files .ebextensions directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run them on the server, you have two options to accomplish this:

1. [Set up a cronjob](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/) on the server to execute the tasks you want to schedule
2. SSH into the server using `eb ssh`, and execute the commands manually. In order for this to work, you need to [set up a ssh key-pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html) for your instance.